# Unable to find class in same project when loading service

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, location, google-play-services

I'm trying to instantiate a service for testing a location system we're putting together. Basically, I took this service: http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html and imported the relevant classes into my project. What I want is a background service that will propagate mock locations to all `LocationClient`s while its running.

The manifest for my project looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="air.com.sourceco.mobile.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="air.com.sourceco.mobile" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <service android:name="com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService"
            android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have a two projects in Eclipse - my original `Sourceco` project, which has the functionality I want to test, and my `SourcecoTest` project, which has the JUnit tests. Here are the classes I have (`TestLocation`, `SendMockLocationService`, and `LocationUtils` are copied almost verbatim from the google site, with the exception that they have been changed to different test locations).

`LocationHelperTest.java` (The main class I'm working with, in package `com.sourceco.mobile.location.test`):

```
package com.sourceco.mobile.location.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.sourceco.mobile.location.GPLocationServicesConsumer;

public class LocationHelperTest extends AndroidTestCase implements ConnectionCallbacks {

  private GPLocationServicesConsumer mConsumer;

  // According to the documentation, we should always set the provider to "flp",
  // which is the location provider code that Location Services puts into the
  // Location objects it sends out.
  public static final String PROVIDER = "flp";

  // Latitude and Longitude of:
  // Captain Tony's Saloon, 428 Greene Street, Key West, FL 33040
  public static final double LAT = 24.558760;
  public static final double LON = -81.805434;
  public static final float ACCURACY = 10.0f;

  private Intent mServiceIntent;

  @Override
  public void setUp() {
    // Start our service for mock location processing
    mServiceIntent = new Intent("com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService");
    mContext.startService(mServiceIntent);

    mConsumer = new GPLocationServicesConsumer(mContext);
    mConsumer.notifyActivityCreated();
    mConsumer.notifyActivityStarted();

  }

  @Override
  public void tearDown() {
    mContext.stopService(mServiceIntent);
  }

  public Location createLocation(double lat, double lon, float acc) {
    Location newLocation = new Location(PROVIDER);
    newLocation.setLatitude(lat);
    newLocation.setLongitude(lon);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(acc);
    return newLocation;
  }

  public void testLocationRetrieval() throws InterruptedException {
    // Arrange
    Location mockLocation = createLocation(LAT, LON, ACCURACY);

    // Act
    Location testLocation = mConsumer.getLocation();

    // Assert
    assertEquals("Latitudes should be equal", mockLocation.getLatitude(), testLocation.getLatitude());
    assertEquals("Longitudes should be equal", mockLocation.getLongitude(), testLocation.getLongitude());
    assertEquals("Accuracies should be equal", mockLocation.getAccuracy(), testLocation.getAccuracy());
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisconnected() {

  }
}
```

When I run the test, though, I get the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service 
    com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
    "com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService" on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", 
    zip file "/data/app/air.com.sourceco.mobile.test-2.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/air.com.sourceco.mobile.test-2, 
    /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2556)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
    "com.sourceco.mobile.location.test.SendMockLocationService" on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", 
    zip file "/data/app/air.com.sourceco.mobile.test-2.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/air.com.sourceco.mobile.test-2, 
    /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2553)
    ... 10 more
```

Originally, I thought this was caused by google-play-services not being imported correctly, but it is imported in the original Sourceco project, and that doesn't seem to be what it's complaining about. Instead, it's complaining that it can't find the class definition for `SendMockLocationService`.

Any idea what could be happening here? I'm not quite sure why this service won't start up for my test.

Comment: Do you actually have that class in your test project? Bear in mind that neither the test project nor the project being tested is the `com.sourceco.mobile.location.test` package.

Comment: Well, the test project does have that package. The class LocationHelperTest is in the package. Also, I double-checked, and I moved the SendMockLocationService into that package, as well.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The targetPackage isn't the same as the package where the source files reside.